# Why $SHELL doesn't change when I run new shell?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

```
 $ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
 $ /bin/ksh93
 $ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
 $ file /bin/ksh93
/bin/ksh93: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped

 $ getent passwd test111
test111:x:1008:1008:,,,:/tmp:/bin/ksh93
 $ ssh test@localhost
test@localhost's password:
 $ echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh93
 $ bash
 $ echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh93
```

I expect the `$SHELL` to change after running another shell. Why doesn't it?

P.S. However the shell does change, only $SHELL variable remains the same:

```
 $ dash
 $ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
 $ T=test ; [[ $T = *est ]] && echo ok
dash: [[: not found
```

Comment: use `echo $0` to get the current shell

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't expect this variable to change. It is used to store the path to your default shell, i.e. the one stored in the password database, not which shell you're currently running.

Answer (score 9):

`SHELL` is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08). Quoting:

> SHELL
>       This variable shall represent a pathname of the user's preferred
>       command language interpreter. [...]

Running a different shell does not necessarily indicate a change in the user's preference.

It is good to learn the types of things that POSIX specifies and where to search for them since most *.nix systems aim for POSIX compliance. Environment variables are one of those things.

Answer (score -4):

The SHELL variable stores the **parent shell for your session, which sometimes matches with your default login shell**. The $SHELL is the parent shell which spawned the current session.

so, if i use bash for my user and do this: `chsh -s /bin/zsh user`, when I do `echo $SHELL`, the shell displayed will still be `BASH`.

see [this article](http://linuxg.net/the-unix-and-linux-shell-variable-shell/).

Comment: The article you link to is incorrect. That's the other way around, i.e. SHELL stores your default login shell (at the last login time) which sometimes match your parent shell. This variable is never modified by your parent or current shell. The only action they might do is setting it if (unexpectedly) unset.